# VBA search function to search two cells in a row for a specific word

Tags: string, excel, vba, search, text

I have been trying to write a search function in VBA to search for a specific word - or rather the lack thereof - in cells. I need to go through a range of cells. There are two columns, if neither one of the cells a row contains the word, the row should be flagged - e.g. change colors. I am able to search one column, but when I try to search across two columns Excel bombs out. The columns are contained in a Pivot Table.

I have attached my code below. Any recommendations?

```
Private Sub AnalyseCTCN_Click()
Dim CT2CFN1 As Range 'CT2CFN1 is column 1
Dim CT2CFN2 As Range 'CT2CFN2 is column 2
Dim CT2CFN As Range

Set CT2CFN1 = Intersect(PivotTables("PivotTableCTCN").PivotFields("CUST_TYPE").PivotItems("2").DataRange.EntireRow, _
PivotTables("PivotTableCTCN").PivotFields("CUST_FULL_NAME_1").DataRange)
Set CT2CFN2 = Intersect(PivotTables("PivotTableCTCN").PivotFields("CUST_TYPE").PivotItems("2").DataRange.EntireRow, _
PivotTables("PivotTableCTCN").PivotFields("CUST_FULL_NAME_2").DataRange)
Set CT2CFN = Union(CT2CFN1, CT2CFN2)

Dim d As Range
Dim c As Range
For Each d In CT2CFN1
For Each c In CT2CFN2
If InStr(1, d, "T/A", 1) = 0 And InStr(1, c, "T/A", 1) = 0 Then
d.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
Next c
Next d

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not apply conditional formatting on the range? or use Find?  Where does it error?

Comment: For some reason conditional formatting does not want to work on the pivot table (which I am new to). No error occurs, excel simply does not seem capable of processing the code without freezing.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code using F8, you can see where it hangs/errors then.